# PHP loop increment randomly?

Tags: php, loops, random, increment

We all know the basic

```
$i = 1;

while ($i<100){
    echo $i;
    $i++
}
```

Question: How do I increment $i by a random number between 1 and 5 each time it loops?

Comment: `if` is not a looping statement. :|

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Exactly like you described it in words: By increment it with a random number between 1 and 5.

```
while ($i < 1000) {
  echo $i;
  $i += rand(1,5);
}
```

[`rand()`](http://php.net/rand)

Answer (score 5):

In one line:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 1000; $i += rand(1, 5)) echo $i;
```

Comment: Semantically and operationally identical though, I have +1ed yours as well

Answer (score 1):

`mt_rand` is faster and uses uses the Mersenne Twister algorythm (1997)

```
while ($i < 1000) {
  echo $i;
  $i += mt_rand(1,5);
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see this is not true